# Changing some column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Large Pandas DataFrame. In this Data frame I created new columns. I write a code to find the index of some values that I want in this Dataframe. Then I want to change the new Columns values to True.

This is the code for finding the indexes:

```
def getIndexes(dfObj, value):
    ''' Get index positions of value in dataframe i.e. dfObj.'''
    listOfPos = list()
    # Get bool dataframe with True at positions where the given value exists
    result = dfObj.isin([value])
    # Get list of columns that contains the value
    seriesObj = result.any()
    columnNames = list(seriesObj[seriesObj == True].index)
    # Iterate over list of columns and fetch the rows indexes where value exists
    for col in columnNames:
        rows = list(result[col][result[col] == True].index)
        for row in rows:
            listOfPos.append((row, col))
    # Return a list of tuples indicating the positions of value in the dataframe
    return listOfPos
```

In addition, I use this function to find the values and change them in the dataframe with this:

```
for i in icd_keys:
    index_icd = getIndexes(d,i)
    for j in range(len(index_icd)):
        d.iloc[index_icd[j][0]][i] = True
    print(i)
```

It is working, however, because I have a really large dataFrame it took a long time.
I was wondering if you have any suggestion to make this process faster.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to find the index? Cant you just [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the value with `True`?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Yes, I have no Idea where are these values are in the dataframe. I first want to make sure where are they, and if they were exist change that column.